# Real analysis: Uniqueness of minimum for a function

Tags: real-analysis

There is a function, say $f(x)$ from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which has strictly positive second derivative,

$$
f''(x)>0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

I need to show that the function has a unique global minimum. One way to do this is to use Taylor's series expansion to show that the function has a local minimum. Then show that the function is convex because of the positive second derivative. Then show that  a convex function has a unique global minimum.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not true: consider, for example, $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: @Rigel maybe "no more than one global minimum"?

Comment: @Rigel: If there is a local minimum, then it a global minimum too, right?

Comment: The point is that you can prove that there is *at most* one minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. If you  take $f(x)=\exp(x)$ then this fails. However, one thing that is true is  that if $f$ has a local minimum, it is unique and a global minimum.

By the second derivatives test, we have that if $f'(x_0)=0$ somewhere then because $f''(x_0)>0$, this is a local minimum. On the other hand, $f''>0$ means that $f'$ is strictly increasing, so it has only one zero. Hence the critical point is unique. Furthermore, because $f$ is decreasing for $x<x_0$ and increasing for $x>x_0$, $f(x_0)$ is a global minimum.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Antonios

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ attains its global minimum at two distinct points $x_0$ and $x_1$, with $x_0<x_1$. You know that $f'(x_0)=f'(x_1)=0$. This is impossible, since $\bigl(\forall x\in[x_0,x_1]\bigr):f''(x)>0$, which implies that $f'$ is strictly increasing in $[x_0,x_1]$.

Comment: $f^\prime(x_0)=f^\prime(x_1)=0$

Comment: yes, $f'(x_0)=f'(x_1)=0$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoséCarlosSantos